# Any shell command to directly let dein.vim to install plugins?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim

Any shell command to directly let dein.vim to install plugins?

I want to set up my own (Neo)Vim environment on a docker container. It would be nice if I could install vim plugins on only Dockerfile (without executing `nvim`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with `-c` flag.

```
nvim -c 'call dein#install() | q'
```

This will open up vim run commands (in this case dein#install and quit)

Comment: Thanks sudo. That's what I wanted!